# Views In UIScrollView lose interaction When Rotated to Landscape

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2

I have a `UIViewController` that by default contains a `UIScrollView` and a container view inside. Inside the container view, I am adding a set of views programatically. 
In portrait mode everything works fine but once the device is rotated to landscape, the views looses interaction though I can still scroll and the first view has interaction!

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        // used to adjust scrollview height
        self.view.setupContentViewForViewWithScroll(contentView: contentView)

        let lastView : UIView! = contentView.subviews.last
        let height = lastView.frame.size.height
        let pos = lastView.frame.origin.y
        let sizeOfContent = height + pos + 10

        ScrollView.contentSize.height = sizeOfContent
        ScrollView.contentSize.width = self.view.frame.width
    }

        // adding views for loop...

        let Description = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, CGFloat(position), self.view.frame.size.width-10, 40))
        contentView.addSubview(Description) // contentView is the container
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Views In UIScrollView lose interaction When Rotated to Landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314106/views-in-uiscrollview-lose-interaction-when-rotated-to-landscape)

Comment: my mistake, i asked a different question with the same title. i fixed it now

Comment: It's OK; a moderator will spot my flag and close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried removing the container view and adding the views (UILabel...) to the scrollview directly and now the interaction is normal when rotating the device which is strange. if someone can explain this behaviour please tell.

Comment: This isn't the case for me. Still not working when orientation changes to landscape... Very strange.